# Assign Same Value to Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, key, serialization

I faced a problem while using Django with React. I am using Django Rest Framework to serialize objects but then I faced an error in React's frontend saying that each object needs a "key" property.

I have been wondering if it's possible, seeing that there is a default ID, to add another field in Rest Framework that has the same value as Django model's primary key field? Putting into context, let's say I have this:

```py
# models.py

class Todo(models.Model):
    # the id field is auto-generated by django
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=50)
    desc = models.TextField(_('description'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Is it possible if I can do something like this below?

```py
# serializers.py

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # assign the value of id to a new field named "key"            <-- this action!!!
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, trim_whitespace=True)
    desc = serializers.CharField(max_length=500, allow_blank=True)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['id', 'key', 'title', 'desc', 'level', 'created']
```

The reason that I want to do this is that React recognizes the "key" property instead of "id", which lead me to this problem. At the same time, I don't want to discard the "id" column as migrating the data will be heavy work (there are already entries inside).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

```
key = serializers.IntegerField()
```

and then assign key-value as id-value in your class view.

If you do not want to use a class view to assign value, you can use custom objects on the serializer class and set key-value.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this:

```
key = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', read_only=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with react, but as far as I know, a key is required for react to keep track of an item in a loop. Therefore a key needs to be unique and an ID can be used for this.

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo) =>
  <li key={todo.id}>    
      {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

You could also use the index of the loop.

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo, index) =>
  // Only do this if items have no stable IDs  
  <li key={index}>    
      {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```

Also, add `read_only_fields = ('id',)` to you Meta class of the serializer